# Calculating $\oint_{|z| = 3} \frac{z^3e^{1/z}}{z^3+1}dz$ using a substitution

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

So I've tried to calculate $$\oint_{|z| = 3} \frac{z^3e^{1/z}}{z^3+1}dz$$ using the substitution $w = \frac{1}{z}$ but I couldn't do anything after that. I believe I'm supposed to get to a point where I can apply the Residue Theorem to calculate the integral. The solution is $-2\pi i$ Any tips?

Comment: So when you make the substitution, what integral do you get?

Comment: I get $\oint_{|z| = 3}\frac{e^w}{1 + w^3}$

Comment: You seem to have forgotten the substitution in $dz$. Also, what curve is the circle $\lvert z\rvert = 3$ mapped to under $w = 1/z$? And be careful with the orientations of the curves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the substitution $z\to \frac{1}{w}$ we have that $\frac{z^3 e^{1/z}}{z^3+1}\,dz$ is mapped into 
$$-\frac{e^w}{w^5+w^2}\,dw $$
and the integration range $|z|=3$, counter-clockwise oriented, is mapped into the integration range $|w|=\frac{1}{3}$, clockwise oriented. It follows that
$$ \oint_{|z|=3}\frac{z^3 e^{1/z}}{z^3+1}\,dz = \oint_{|w|=\frac{1}{3}}\frac{e^w}{w^5+w^2}\,dw =2\pi i\cdot\text{Res}\left(\frac{e^w}{w^5+w^2},w=0\right)$$
where $w=0$ is a double pole for the new integrand function, and the only one enclosed by the integration path. Since in a neighbourhood of the origin we have
$$ \frac{e^w}{1+w^3} = 1+w+O(w^2) $$
the wanted residue equals $1$ and
$$ \oint_{|z|=3}\frac{z^3 e^{1/z}}{z^3+1}\,dz = \color{red}{2\pi i}.$$

Comment: Do you mind explaining why you expand only $\frac{e^w}{1 + w^3}$ and not $\frac{e^w}{w^5 + w^2}$ ?

Comment: @IamJay: simply because $$\frac{e^w}{w^5+w^2}=\frac{1}{w^2}\cdot\frac{e^w}{1+w^3}$$ and we want the coefficient of $\frac{1}{w}$, i.e. the coefficient of $w$ in $\frac{e^w}{1+w^3}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you know about Laurent series you may rewrite the integrand as
$$ e^{1/z} \left(1+ \frac{1}{z^3}\right)^{-1}= (1+\frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{2! z^2} + ...) (1-\frac{1}{z^3} +...) = 1+\frac{1}{z} + O(\frac{1}{z^2})$$
(the Laurent series converging for $|z|=3$) and the result follows by residue calculus.

Comment: (+1) way easier than my approach. It looks like we agree on the value of the integral being $\color{red}{+}2\pi i$, correct?

Comment: yes, the value is indeed the same.